# Cargo lipo can't build library despite all necessary components being installed

Tags: ios, xcode, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on building rust libraries for iOS but I just can't get it to work. I've followed the tutorial (from 2019) to the letter but `cargo lipo --release` returns the following error message:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
```

|
= note: the `aarch64-apple-ios` target may not be installed
= help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add aarch64-apple-ios`

Meanwhile, `rustup target add aarch64-apple-ios` returns:

```
info: component 'rust-std' for target 'aarch64-apple-ios' is up to date
```

My src/lib.rs looks like this:

```
 1 use std::os::raw::{c_char};
 2 use std::ffi::{CString, CStr};
 3 
 4 #[no_mangle]
 5 pub extern fn rust_hello(to: *const c_char) -> *mut c_char {
 6     let c_str = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(to) };
 7     let recipient = match c_str.to_str() {
 8         Err(_) => "there",
 9         Ok(string) => string,
 10     };
 11     CString::new("Hello ".to_owned() + recipient).unwrap().into_raw()
 12 }
 13 
 14 #[no_mangle]
 15 pub extern fn rust_hello_free(s: *mut c_char) {
 16     unsafe {
 17         if s.is_null() { return }
 18         CString::from_raw(s)
 19     };
 20 }
```

And my Cargo.toml looks like this:

```
          1 [package]
          2 name = "rust"
          3 version = "0.1.0"
          4 edition = "2021"
          5 
          6 [lib]
          7 name = "rust"
          8 crate-type = ["staticlib", "cdylib"]
          9 
          10 # See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-     lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
          11 
          12 [dependencies]
```

Comment: Are yous sure ?

Comment: Lmfao yes I’m sure  been tryna solve for 2 days straight lmfao

Comment: 2 days and you can't make a question without line numbers ? Again, Are you sure ? I see you use an external command of cargo you should ask them directly

Comment: I wasn't aware line numbers weren't "cool" on this very nerdy website? I just copied and pasted directly from vim lol